# Variance of trade length for the OU-process

Tags: pairs-trading, ornstein-uhlenbeck

Based on the article by [Bertram (2010)](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1505073), I am trying to calculate the variance of the trade length stated in equation [10] of the paper. However, the weights used has a specification that I cannot quite get my head around.
My question is, how do I evaluate the infinite sum for the weights as in this equation:

$w_1(z)=(\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Gamma(k/2)(\sqrt{2}z)^k/k!) - (\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Gamma(k/2)(\sqrt{2}z)^k/k!)^2$

$w_2(z)=\Gamma((2k-1)/2)\Psi((2k-1)/2)(\sqrt{2}x)$

Where $\Psi$ is the digamma function. I have considered the answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/384355/method-to-evaluate-an-infinite-sum-of-ratio-of-gamma-functions-how-does-mathema) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/419869/sum-of-infinite-series-with-the-gamma-function), but it is still not clear to me how I should proceed.

Any help is appreciated!

I post here as the question is related to a quantitative trading strategy.